# Can't load Linux kernel on NVME SSD

Tags: boot

I want to install both Ubuntu and win10 into my laptop, now Windows works fine. I created a EFI partition on my SSD and put Ubuntu ISO into it. I entered the boot menu and selected the new option and then selected "try ubuntu without installing", then it failed to load and showed "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system".
I also tried putting the ISO into a U-disk, but the installer couldn't recognize my SSD in the partition stage in which I can choose where to put /boot while it could create partitions in the U-disk.
I searched the Internet and found that switching to AHCI mode may help, but I only have a NVME SSD using a m.2 socket and can't find AHCI mode in my BIOS settings.

Comment: What brand/model system? What version of Ubuntu. If newer system best to use newest Ubuntu or 22.04LTS or 22.10. And then best to boot both systems in UEFI boot mode unless very old system. USB USB flash drive as installer. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb  and install in UEFI mode: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview Ubuntu & Windows will share same ESP - efi system partition.

Comment: Do I need to put Ubuntu EFI and Windows EFI into one ESP partition? I've tried creating several ESP partitions in my drive, but got the message mentioned above.

Comment: Only one ESP per drive. While specs may allow more than one, most UEFI implementations only allow one.